# Pegar id onclick e enviar valores via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

Eu tenho uma lista de tarefas, nela tem a parte de status, que mostra por exemplo **'Em Teste'** e um botão de **Aprovar**.

Eu estou tentando com que esse botão **Aprovar** ao ser clicado pegue o Id da tarefa e envie um update nela para alterar seu status.

Mas até agora não sei como fazer, estava tentando fazer via Ajax com `onClick`, mas não consegui nada até agora.

Alguém pode me dar uma caminho?

**Botão**

```
<a id="approved" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**ID**

```
<li class="list-group-item id-task" id="<?php echo $row['TasksId']; ?>">
```

**Código da Tarefa**

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <ul id="sortable" class="list-group reorder-task-list">                
                    <?php                                                                               
                    $rows = $auth_task->select();                       
                    foreach($rows as $row): ?>
                        <li class="list-group-item id-task" id="<?php echo $row['TasksId']; ?>">
                            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <h5 class="delivery-line">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <?php echo$row['Delivery'];?>
                            </h5>

                            <?php 
                                if($row['Status'] == 'Em Processo'){
                                    echo "<span class=\"badge\" style=\"background-color:#67A6DF\">Em Processo</span>";
                                }
                                elseif ($row['Status'] == 'Teste') {
                                    echo "<span class=\"badge\" style=\"background-color:#FCB529\">Em Teste</span>";
                                }
                                elseif ($row['Status'] == 'Aprovada'){
                                    echo "<span class=\"badge\" style=\"background-color:#43A995\">Aprovada</span>";
                                }                               
                            ?>
                        <div>
                            <h4 class="line-center">                                                            
                            <strong><?php echo $row['Project'];?></strong>
                            </h4>                                                               
                        </div>  
                        <h6 class="line-center" ><?php echo $row['Subject'];?></h6>                     
                        <hr>                            
                        <h4 class="company-line line-center">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <?php echo $row['CompanyFantasy'];?>                                
                        </h4>
                        <?php if($userRow['Level'] == 'Admin'):?>
                        <div class="footer-li">
                            <a href="" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Estatística"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>    
                            <a href="" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Abrir"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a href="" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enviar Para Teste"><i class="fa fa-flask fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a id="approved" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a href="" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancelar"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>                              
                        </div><!-- <div class="footer-li"> -->                          
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </li>                               
                    <?php endforeach; ?>                      
                </ul>
              </div><!-- <div class="panel-body"> -->
```

Comment: Pode postar o seu JavaScript?

Comment: Acho mais fácil você fazer isso sem ajax, na forma de link mesmo passando por parâmetro a ação e o id da tarefa.

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel tem alguma documentação para eu dar uma lida?

Comment: @AllanAndrade Não passei disso 
`$('#approved').on('click',function(){
  var taskid=$(this).find('li').attr('id');
    
  $.ajax({
            url: './task.php',
            type: 'POST',                
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {                  
               window.location.reload();                      
            }                 
        });
 });`

Comment: Terá um botão só para todas as tarefas? Explica melhor como vc quer que funcione?

Comment: @AllanAndrade ele monta um botão para cada tarefa, se eu clicar no botão de aprovar ele vai trocar o valor da tarefa dentro do banco, um update, para trocar o status dele.

Eu consegui pegar o ID `<a href=?action=approved&TasksId=<?php echo $row['TasksId']; ?> id="approved" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`

Mas meu problema é que estou utilizando Class e PDO.

Comment: Só lí seu comentário anterior agora, então acho que é como o @FabianoCacinPinel falou... só pode ter um ID, muda por classe, pega ID relativo ao objeto que recebeu o clique e posta via AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exemplo usando o ajax:

Não pode conter elementos com IDs repetidos dentro de uma página html então mude

**de**

```
<a id="approved" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar">
```

**para**

```
<a class="approved" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar">
```

No js que você fez vai ficar assim:

```
<script>
    $('.approved').on('click',function(){ 

        var taskid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

        $.ajax({ 
            url: './task.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { action: 'aprovar', ID: taskid },
            success: function(data) { 
                window.location.reload(); 
            } 
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

No arquivo task.php vai ter algo assim:

```
<?php

if( $_GET['action'] == 'aprovar' and ! empty( $_GET['ID'] ) ){

    // o código que atualiza o banco

}
```

Acredito que é isso

Comment: Muito obrigado, erra isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu geralmente faço como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<a id="approved" class="flex-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar" data-id="<?php echo $row['TasksId'];?>"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("a#approved").click(function(){
      var id_task = $(this).attr('data-id');

      $.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.seusite.com.br/script.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {id:id_task}

       success: function(callback){
          alert(callback);
       }
      });
   });
});
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
echo 'Retornou: '.$_POST['id'];
?>
```

O que fiz foi colocar um atributo na tag `<a>` chamado **data-id** (poderia ser qualquer nome) e dentro dele passei a ID da tarefa.

Já no jQuery eu criei um código que ao clicar no link/botão ele pegaria o que está na tag `data-id`que seria a ID da tarefa e passaria via ajax para um arquivo PHP chamado **script.php** (pode ser qualquer nome)